# SCIP and Visual Studi: error LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, lnk2019, scip

I want to solve the n-queens problem using SCIP (version 3.2.1) in Visual Studio 2010 (version 10.0.40219.1).

Source files can be found here: http://scip.zib.de/download/files/Queens.tgz
I did not write any code myself, but just included queens.hpp, scip_exceptions.hpp, queens.cpp and queens_main.cpp in my VS project.

In the project properties I did the following:
`C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> C:\scipoptsuite-3.2.1\scip-3.2.1\src\`.

When building, I get errors like:

```
 LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SCIPaddCons referenced in function "public: __thiscall cipexamples::QueensSolver::QueensSolver(unsigned int)"
```

I understand that I will have to link SCIP libraries to my project? But I do not know which ones and where to find them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the SCIP Optimization Suite first to obtain the `libscipopt` that you need to link to your project. It will contain everything necessary to work with SCIP.

Alternatively, you may also just use the precompiled dlls from the webpage:
http://scip.zib.de/#download